# iPhone send SMS through Bluetooth

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth

From what I read Apple seems to be quiet protective over sending SMS messages programmatically however they do have such classes as MFMessageComposeViewController to allow the fields to be filled or the sms:// url or even SMSTO for QR codes. However is there a way to automate it via Bluetooth from say a Mac. Thus allowing users to send text messages via their computer (I know you can receive text messages but I don't know if you can send them).

Comment: You can do anything if you write your own library or class that looks and acts like "`MFMessageComposeViewController`".  However, if you want other people to be able to use it in other apps, you'll have to make it available as a library and with an API that developers can hook into.

Comment: But how would I be able to send an SMS as I understand it Apple does not have public access APIs to send an SMS automatically.

Comment: I'm confused by your question then.  Can you describe a little bit more clearly what you are trying to do?  Do you want to automate *composing* SMS messages on the phone and then sending them out via the phone's normal SMS method?

Comment: Apple gives ways to compose an SMS however there is no way, that I am aware of, to automatically send one from your phone over bluetooth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

iOS devices support the Message Access Profile ( MAP ) that is used for sending SMS and being notified of incoming SMS BUT Apple explicitly states in their Bluetooth Guidelines that iOS devices do not support sending messages.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/hardwaredrivers/bluetoothdesignguidelines.pdf ( section 2.2.3 Message Access Profile ( MAP ))

> Not provide a user interface for sending messages. iOS devices do not
>   support sending messages using MAP

Comment: Thans, it is what I guessed but I had hoped it was just my inexperience that made me think that.