# AT command for sms through smartphone

Tags: at-command

I am connecting my iPhone to windows laptop through 32feet blue tooth connection in hands free profile. I am able to initiate call in the iphone using AT commands through the blue tooth connection. But I am not able to send sms from the beginning. I am sending the following AT commands

```
  "ATE\r",
  "AT\r",
  "AT+CMGF=1\r",
  "AT+CMGS=\"" + phoneNumber + "\"\r",
  "SMS over Bluetooth\n",
  $"{26}"
```

For all the above AT commands the smartphone is returning an Error except for the AT command where the response is OK. I am not sure what are the AT commands we need to send to a smartphone to make it send SMS to any number.

P.S : Apple had initially blocked sending sms from bluetooth but now I am seeing some apps sending sms through bluetooth in iPhones.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iPhone send SMS through Bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873300/iphone-send-sms-through-bluetooth)

Comment: I am able to send sms over bluetooth using callcenter app with my iPhone. So it is possible to do it but I don't know how.

Comment: But your call centre application doesn't use the above AT commands, otherwise you could have sniffed them ;-)

Comment: You mean to say Apple is blocking AT commands for sms but allowing it for calls. Because I am able to initiate a call through AT commands

Comment: Yes, Apple is very restrictive in these matters.

Comment: AT command is working for iPhone to initiate a call but not for sms. Why will Apple allow call but not sms? I am not clear with that.

Comment: A simple example: A working AT command set is required to make calls for all hands-free car kits, but not to send SMS messages.